# Add multiple search criteria to SwiftUI searchbar?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, filtering, swiftui-list

I think i'm just too dumb to manage this. I'm trying to add more criterias to my searchable list in SwiftUI. The List is connected to a Firestore Database. Somehow, I can't figure out how to add more criterias to the Searchbar.
I now have the criteria "str" (basically means Street), but I want to add "sn" (serialnumber) and like 2-3 more. At the end, you should be able to search "[Street Serialnumber...]" all in one Searchbar.

Thank you for helping

Code:

```
struct CustomSearchBar : View {
    
    @State var txt = ""
    @Binding var data : [dataType]
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            HStack{
                
                TextField("Nach Seriennummer suchen", text: self.$txt).opacity(100).foregroundColor(.black)
                
                if self.txt != ""{
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        self.txt = ""
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("Abbrechen")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }

            }.padding()
            
            if self.txt != ""{
                
                if
                    self.data.filter({$0.str.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0 {
                        
                    Text("Es wurde kein Gerät mit dieser Seriennummer gefunden").foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.6)).padding()
                    
                }

                
                else{
                    
                    List(self.data.filter{$0.str.contains(self.txt.lowercased())}){i in
                            
                    NavigationLink(destination: Detail(data: i)) {
                        
                        Text(i.sn)
                        }
                         
                        Text(i.typ)
                    
                        
                    }.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5)
                    
                }

            }
            
            
        }.background(Color.white)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your criteria use some sort of keyword, like "sn: 12345", "str: 1600 Pennsylvania Ave."? If not, how do you know which part of the search string applies to each criterion?

Comment: @NRitH
For now, if i search for example Pennsylvania Ave., it will search through all documents if they match the keyword Pennsylvania Ave. and list them.
str, sn... are dataTypes and Documents from my Firestore database. They are all declared as Strings. 
Example:
let sn = i.get("Seriennummer") as! String
The only thing i need is to add sn or other types as criteria. 
now ther is just "self.data.filter({$0.str.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0"
but i want to have it (Example)
self.data.filter({$0.str, sn.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0